# Problem while installing LEMP on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, mysql, php, nginx

I have been trying to install the LEMP stack on Linux Mint following these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

However, when I tried to load http://192.168.1.5 as the final step, I got

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.1.5 took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Everything seemed to be working fine before that.

The content of the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name 192.168.1.5;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if nginx is the only program listening to port 80. For example if you have apache2 running as well this is possible since both servers listen to the same port and confusion happens.
Here is a useful link https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-what-running-on-port-80-command/
Also, depending on the browser you are using when writing the url, play a little with the url, specify the port: 192.168.1.5:80 or try with the server domain.